# Use of Delegates to Communicate Between View Controllers

Tags: ios

After asking some questions, I learned how to send orders from one view controller to another and managed to write the code its working but nothing happens...

In my project I have two view controllers named as `sayfa1` and `sayfa23`. When a button at `sayfa1` is clicked it will open up `sayfa23` and write on a label (random hello see the code below) but its not happening. On simulator that button only opens up the `sayfa23` and thats it nothing happening to label. If you look at the code you can understand it better.

sayfa1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol sayfa1Delegate <NSObject>

- (void)dealWithButton1;

@end


@interface sayfa1 : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<sayfa1Delegate> delegate;

@end
```

sayfa1.m

```
#import "sayfa1.h"

@interface sayfa1 ()

@end

@implementation sayfa1

@synthesize delegate;

-(IBAction)button
{
    [delegate dealWithButton1];
}

@end
```

sayfa23.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sayfa1.h"

@interface sayfa23 : UIViewController <sayfa1Delegate> 
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    sayfa1 *vc1 ;
}

@end
```

sayfa23.m

```
#import "sayfa23.h"
#import "sayfa1.h"

@interface sayfa23 ()

@end

@implementation sayfa23

- (void)dealWithButton1
{
    vc1.delegate = self;    
    int random_num;
    random_num = (arc4random() % 5 - 1) + 1;
    if (random_num == 1)
    { 
        label.text = @"hello1";    
    }
    else if (random_num == 2)
        label.text = @"hello2";
    else if (random_num == 3)
        label.text = @"hello3";
    else if (random_num == 4)
        label.text = @"hello4";
}

@end
```

After writing this code I connected the button to `sayfa23` so it will open the new page also I connected that button to `sayfa1` to receive button actions and I connected label (on `sayfa23`) to `sayfa23` receive label orders. But as I say nothing happens no errors and no hello what I am doing wrong? I imported `sayfa1.h` or `sayfa23.h` at the top of some of my h files cause Xcode give me an error about not defined and solved that problem but is it my mistake or something else.

Example of I want.

- User opens the app
- `sayfa1` shown on screen
- User clicks the button and `sayfa23` is shown the label text on `sayfa23` is changed by the button which is at `sayfa1` it write random hello1..2..3 etc...

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `vc1` when you execute `vc1.delegate = self;`?

Comment: I doubt that method is ever being called. @PhillipMills he is assigning the delegate inside the delegate method.

Comment: Good point!  Using the delegate as a receiver before trying to set it is a bad idea.  (Sometimes the existence of one known pattern of error obscures another.)

Comment: Yes I agree with you I also think that method is never called but how can I solve it. 

Also can I attach a code at the starting point of the view controller I mean when view controller comes up it automatically writes on a label ? But don't get confused I know how to write on a label on storyboard I want a my random hello code to run when a view controller is opened.

Comment: If nothing happens, why do you say that it's working?

Comment: It builds with no errors but nothing happens.Any idea how to solve it please !!!

Comment: You say that you want a button on `sayfa1` to open `sayfa23` and set a text label on `sayfa23`, then _no_ delegates are required. You'd just have `sayfa1` open `sayfa23` and `sayfa23`'s `viewDidLoad` would set the contents of the label. The question was phrased in terms of delegates and led to answers below that solve a different problem, that if you click on a button in `sayfa23` it can update something back on `sayfa1` (or send a message to `sayfa1` that the button was clicked). But if all you want is for button on `sayfa1` to open `sayfa23` and set text label, no delegates are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rereading your question, you ask how your first view controller can open the second view controller and set a text box. If that is, indeed, what you are trying to do, it's a far simpler question, no delegate protocol or delegates required at all.

The two previous answers were informed by the discussion of delegates, but that's designed to solve a different problem. Delegates are only required if you need your second controller to pass something back to the first controller. But if you just want your second controller to receive something from the first controller, it's as simple as:

```
//  FirstViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

with an implementation like:

```
//  FirstViewController.m

#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

- (NSString *)generateRandomText
{
    NSString *result;

    int random_num;
    random_num = (arc4random() % 5 - 1) + 1;
    if (random_num == 1)
        result = @"hello1";    
    else if (random_num == 2)
        result = @"hello2";
    else if (random_num == 3)
        result = @"hello3";
    else if (random_num == 4)
        result = @"hello4";

    return result;
}

// if you're using NIBs, it might be something like...
// you only need this method if you're using NIBs and you've manually hooked a button up to this
// if you're using segues, get rid of `goToNextViewController` and just use the following `prepareForSegue

- (IBAction)goToNextViewController:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    secondController.textFromParent = [self generateRandomText];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
}

// if you're using segues, give your segue an identifier, e.g. toSecondViewSegue, in Interface Builder and reference the exact same identifier here
// if you're not using segues, you don't need this prepareForSegue method

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSecondViewSegue"])
    {
        SecondViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        destinationController.textFromParent = [self generateRandomText];
    }
}

@end
```

And your second controller might look like:

```
//  SecondViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *textFromParent;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

With an implementation like:

```
//  SecondViewController.m

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize textFromParent = _textFromParent;
@synthesize label = _label;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.label.text = self.textFromParent;
}

@end
```

Comment: I will try this method and share the results with you yes I want my first view controller to send something to second.

Comment: I pasted the codes you wrote and created two view controllers then assigned them as firstviewc... and second vie... later I put one button to firstviewcontroller and one label to secondviewcontroller.I connected button to nextviewcontroller(goto next viewco..) and label to secondviewcontoller(as label).In the simulator there are two problems the button don't open the second viewcontrolelr but its oke I connected them usig the storyboard also at second page the label is not showing any kind of text it was there but its empty no words in it why ?

Comment: @bugrasezer My code sample presumed you were using NIBs and had a button hooked up to manually invoke `pushViewController` that would load the next view from a NIB. If you're using storyboards, just set up your button in Interface Builder to segue to the next controller and you'd use `prepareForSegue` as shown in the modified code sample above. (If you are using segues, you no longer need `goToNextViewController`.) Just make sure to supply an identifier for your segue in Interface Builder that has the exact same name as the identifier you reference in your `prepareForSegue` code here.

Comment: Changing pages is easy I can do it by storyboards what important is at the secondviewcontroller my there is nothing written on the label its empty in storyboard it has label words on it but in program its empty so I guess program changes it but why now word where is my hello ?

Comment: its not stopts working only nothing written in label its empty(although there is label word on it in storyboard) my button is connected to firstviewcontroleler and my label is connected to secondviewcontroller is there something we forgot ?

Comment: yes I can't join chat cause I don't have reputation also they changed the topic name of this page I will try to do what you say but here is the link of my project maybe you want to look in it.

https://rapidshare.com/files/4103266827/page9.zip

when I put breakpoints simulator shuts down.

Comment: Bottom line, you don't have an identifier specified for your segue in interface builder. Click on the storyboard, click on the segue between the first and second view controller, click on the attributes inspector, and your segue has no identifier. Give it one (such as toSecondViewSegue). Your FirstViewController also does not have the prepareForSegue routine I show in my modified answer above.

Comment: I gave the name you said to segue also I pasted the whole code above but still nothing is written on the label : S

Comment: I will keep that in mind what you say.By the way can I use this method you thought me for other objects as well for ex: another label maybe picture etc what do I need to do adding them inside string works ?

Comment: I am trying to create second hello label just to try added textfromparent2 and label2 add neccesery codes to m and h files but I guess I need to modify the segue too and because that my button is modified for first hello I can't any ideas ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14361/discussion-between-robert-ryan-and-bugra-sezer)

Answer (score 1):

Your first controller should, when it instantiates the second controller, set the second's delegate to point back to the first view controller. Thus your first view controller might look like:

```
//  FirstViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)dealWithButton;

@end

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <FirstViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

with an implementation like:

```
//  FirstViewController.m

#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

- (IBAction)goToNextViewController:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    secondController.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
}

- (void)dealWithButton
{
    NSLog(@"Dealt with button from second controller");
}

@end
```

And your second controller might look like:

```
//  SecondViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@class FirstViewController;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<FirstViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

With an implementation like:

```
//  SecondViewController.m

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize label = _label;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    int random_num;
    random_num = (arc4random() % 5 - 1) + 1;
    if (random_num == 1)
        self.label.text = @"hello1";    
    else if (random_num == 2)
        self.label.text = @"hello2";
    else if (random_num == 3)
        self.label.text = @"hello3";
    else if (random_num == 4)
        self.label.text = @"hello4";

    [self.delegate dealWithButton];
}
@end
```

**Update:**

Your original question did not make it clear as to whether you wanted the label to be on the first controller or the second. My answer above assumed you wanted it on the second controller, but in retrospect, you may have wanted it on the first controller (the delegate). If so, the following code does that. Note carefully that I don't just update the first view controller's label in `dealWithButton`, because that's dangerous, because you don't know if the view is visible (could have been unloaded if you received a `didReceiveMemoryWarning`). So I wait for `viewWillAppear`. So again, the first view controller:

```
//  FirstViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)dealWithButton;

@end

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <FirstViewControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

And its implementation:

```
//  FirstViewController.m

#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()
{
    NSString *_labelText;
}
@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize label = _label;

// if you're using storyboards, it would be like:

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"delegateSegue"])
    {
        SecondViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        FirstViewController *sourceController = segue.sourceViewController;

        destinationController.delegate = sourceController;
    }
}

// if not using storyboards, you probably have a button like:

- (IBAction)goToNextViewController:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    secondController.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
}

- (void)dealWithButton
{
    // note, because this is being called by the second view controller, you should *not* update the UI
    // directly, because you can't be assured this view controller's view is still in memory (if you got
    // a didReceiveMemoryWarning while on the second view controller, this first view controller will 
    // stay in memory, but its view could have been released). So save what you want the label to be,
    // and update it on viewWillAppear (and if the view was released, it will be reloaded by the time
    // you hit viewWillAppear.
    //
    // clearly, if you were doing view controller containment and this was the parent view, you wouldn't
    // want to do this. But I assume you're dealing with a simple push/present view controller situation.

    int random_num;
    random_num = (arc4random() % 5 - 1) + 1;
    if (random_num == 1)
        _labelText = @"hello1";    
    else if (random_num == 2)
        _labelText = @"hello2";
    else if (random_num == 3)
        _labelText = @"hello3";
    else if (random_num == 4)
        _labelText = @"hello4";

    NSLog(@"Dealt with button from second controller");
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.label.text = _labelText;
}

@end
```

And the second view controller:

```
//  SecondViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@class FirstViewController;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<FirstViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

And its implementation:

```
//  SecondViewController.m

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate dealWithButton];
}
@end
```

Comment: I will try these codes in a new project and share the results with you

Comment: When I write the first group of the codes nothing happens and at the second group I think I need to make some debugging.What I want is when user clicks the button the view controller 2 will come to screen and a label on it was changed by the button (which is in viewcontroller1) so I want to transfer data between view controllers.When I use your code in both groups I can't assign my button to make action(right click drag the line thing) only nextviewcontroller shows up.

Comment: @bugrasezer This is obviously just a problem in the basics of hooking up buttons to methods. It's clearly just not getting hooked up correctly in Interface Builder. Put in breakpoints or NSLog statements in your various button methods and you should be able to diagnose which button is not hooked up correctly. Unfortunately, the proper use of hooking up buttons to methods is difficult to describe in comments like this. But I've tested the above code, and it works like a champ, but it's hard for me to remotely debug problems in hooking up stuff in Interface Builder.

Comment: @bugrasezer I don't think you said whether you're using storyboards or NIBs, but I've updated the second half of my answer with the equivalent storyboard logic, `prepareForSegue` (assuming, of course, that you set up your segue identifiers correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following method to your sayfa23's implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    vc1 = [[sayfa1 alloc] init];
    vc1.delegate = self;
}
```

and remove vc1.delegate = self; from your dealWithButton1 method.

**Edit**:
You have to understand that the method dealWithButton1 is never getting called because you are never sending the message to the object. Therefore, you are never setting the delegate of vc1. It is a good point to do some setup using the viewDidLoad method, which is called when the view is loaded. There you can alloc init (create an instance of) the sayfa1 class, and assign it to your property vc1. After you have allocated the object you can send messages to it. You can set the delegate then.

sayfa23.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sayfa1.h"

@interface sayfa23 : UIViewController <sayfa1Delegate> 



{

    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
    @property (nonatomic, strong) sayfa1 *vc1 ;



@end
```

sayfa23.m

```
#import "sayfa23.h"
#import "sayfa1.h"

@interface sayfa23 ()

@end

@implementation sayfa23
@synthesize vc1;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    vc1 = [[sayfa1 alloc] init];
    vc1.delegate = self;
}

- (void)dealWithButton1

{
    int random_num;
    random_num = (arc4random() % 5 - 1) + 1;
    if (random_num == 1)
    { 
        label.text = @"hello1";    
    }
    else if (random_num == 2)
        label.text = @"hello2";
    else if (random_num == 3)
        label.text = @"hello3";
    else if (random_num == 4)
        label.text = @"hello4";
}


@end
```

Comment: I added the code you wrote to sayfa23.h which is vc1 = [[sayf.... but nothing happened later I tried to remove the vc1.delegate = self from the sayfa23.h and still nothing happened.Do I have to remove it from elsewhere ?

Comment: I used the new code you wrote (void)viewdidload still nothing happening : S

Comment: try to replace in sayfa23.h sayfa1 *vc1 ; for @property (nonatomic, strong) sayfa1 *vc1 ;

Comment: what I should I need to replace can you write it again step by step also thanks for your help.

Comment: in sayfa23.h change line----> sayfa1 *vc1 ; for line ----> @property (nonatomic, strong) sayfa1 *vc1 ;

Comment: the property vc1 needs setvc1 to be defined this error comes up in implementation and thats why vc1 in implementation gives an error how can we define it ?

Comment: You have to synthesize it inside the .m, just like you did with delegate. Add @synthesize vc1; just after "@implementation sayfa23" in your sayfa23.m file

Comment: I synthesize it but although I have no errors while building when I click the button a green error shown in Xcode for the vc1 = [[sayfa1 alloc] init]; and says thread.1 break point 3 and when I remove that line same error comes for vc1.delegate = self; whats this ???

Comment: a little bit if you say it step by step maybe I can do it

Comment: I completly removed the codes under view load to check and although its empty it still giving the breakpoint error.

Comment: Did you happen to add a breakpoint to that method? is like a blue arrow on the left of the code, pointing to the right. Like the one on the line 23 on that image: http://www.cocoalab.com/media/becomeanxcoder/05/06_breakpoint.png

Comment: I think I if click right side of the code it adds a breakpoint cause when a right click it says edit delete breakpoint do I have to edit ?

Comment: Delete the breakpoint, and try the code I posted. A breakpoint is a point where the execution of the application stops.

Comment: Some strange thing happened when I left click it adds breakpoint and if I run it still gives me breakpoint error but if I go and right click on those break points(they are disable lighter blue color) then program works fine but still nothing is written on label.I will try the code you wrote right now.

Comment: Breakpoint is not an error. It is a tool for debugging your application. When you set a breakpoint, you are telling xcode that you want your program to stop when it runs into it.

Comment: if I put @ property inside { } of the @interface(below IBOoutlet it still gives me error when I put it outside of the { } it works its still inside the @interface

Comment: Sorry my fault. It should be outside the {}

Comment: I corrected some parts of my code I found that I accidentally added another breakpoint somewhere and now I deleted it now there is nothing about break points when I run but still label is not changed what should we do now...and thanks you very much for your help...

Comment: Did you connect the label in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes label is connected to sayfa23 I right clicked sayfa23 and dragded a the blue line to the label and selected the label.

Comment: how can I do the thing you say can you write it step by step ?

Comment: +1 for the key notion of how to set the delegate. -1 because you should not update the view in `didDealWithButton1`. Not good. If you receive a memory warning on the second view, the first view controller's view may have been released! Update your model, and then update your UI on `viewWillAppear`! See the second half of my answer.

Comment: The comments section is not the place to interactively debug your application.  Please refrain from doing so in the future.

Comment: Please consider moving extended discussions to [chat].