# Unable to access UIlabel of other class in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, class, uilabel

I created two class names with **firstclassViewController** and **secondclassViewController**,
 In my **secondclassViewController**  class i want to access `UIlabel` of **firstclassViewController** and i want to change the value of that `UILabel` to new value.

Here is my code snippet,

**firstclassViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *navLabel;
```

**firstclassViewController.m**

```
navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70,7,180,30)];
navLabel.text = @"Categories";
navLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
navLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[[self.navigationController navigationBar] addSubview:navLabel];
```

**secondclassViewController.m**

```
firstclassViewController.m *Obj=[[firstclassViewController.m alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstclassViewController.m" bundle:nil];
Obj.navLabel.text=@"New Value";
```

But i am unable to change my value of UILabel..

***Any help will be appriciated.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for you to communicate between the secondclassViewController and the firstclassViewController is through the use of delegation.

Check out Rob's answer in this post
[Use of Delegates to Communicate Between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632043/use-of-delegates-to-communicate-between-view-controllers)

The general idea is ... your first controller should set the second's delegate to point back to the first view controller.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this is to pass the `UILabel` object from the first view controller to the second one, in the segue. When you do a `firstclassViewController *Obj = [[firstclassViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstclassViewController" bundle:nil];` you are creating a new instance and so the changes you make to the label is only applicable to this instance of the view controller.

Comment: What you say about allocating a new viewController is right. However, your suggestion only helps him pass data from the first view controller to the second. In this case, he's communicating backwards from the second view controller to the first. He should use delegation in my opinion

Comment: Agreed, it's a lot more elegant that way.