# show next view depending on SOAP message value

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, soap, nsxmlparser

I have a user login page with submit button,On successful login I want to go to next view.For this, I'm calling web service(this will validate data from backend DB) which will return true or false depending on success or fail.This is working fine; that is, I'm able to get value using NSXMLParser as following:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (elementFound) {
        soapResults = [string boolValue];
        //NSLog(@"soapResultss = %@",soapResults);

    }
    if (soapResults)
    {
        x = 1; // x is 1 if username and password are correct.
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;//x is 0 if username and password are incorrect
    }
}
```

Mean while(on success) I'm trying to call next view like this in my "submit button click" method:

```
if(x==0)
    {

    }
    else if(x==1)
    {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
    }
```

But, the problem is, the control is not coming back to "submit button click",that is to the "else if" part.And, i think this is not the correct way to do.What is the correct way to do this? Please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what "the control is not coming back to this" means.

Comment: You need to create a custom delegate protocol in the pushed view controller, with the original view controller as the delegate object.  This is used to return state back to the original view controller when it's popped. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632043/use-of-delegates-to-communicate-between-view-controllers

Comment: Well, this is solved by implementing another method.

Answer (score 0):

You check your this line of code why you are using self with view controller object

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

use this line of code(Object of your ViewController)

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok it looks as if just using TRUE/FALSE wont work in this case..

trying `enum` dataType will be effective

in .h file

```
enum {
    kReceivingSoapData,
    kReceivedIncorrectData,
    kReceivedCorrectData

}receivedSoapResult;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
.....
}
```

in the methods used

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (elementFound) {
        soapResults = [string boolValue];
        //NSLog(@"soapResultss = %@",soapResults);

    }
    if (soapResults)
    {
    receivedSoapResult = kReceivedCorrectData;
    }
    else
    {
      receivedSoapResult = kReceivedIncorrectData;;
    }
}
```

in the action method

```
if(receivedSoapResult == kReceivedIncorrectData)
    {
// incorrect uName and password received
    }
    else if(receivedSoapResult == kReceivedCorrectData)
    {
      //correct password received
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
    }
else{
// still receiving data

}
```

Comment: How does this `enum` improve on `BOOL`; you only ever use 2 values anyway.

Comment: if (x == 0) creates two conditions here ,firstly if the response is yet to be received or resonse received is FALSE.The former condition is taken care of if enum is used.

Comment: You don't show initializing `receivedSoapResult` to `kReceivingSoapData` so it's not obvious that it's used.  Also you aren't even solving the right issue; his issue is with the view controller "not coming back to submit button click".